# Firefox Add-on: page mod include pattern won't match

Tags: firefox-addon, pattern-matching, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to add global hotkey support to Spotify (and others). For this I have to execute a content script in the player app iframe, but no matter what pattern I try Firefox just won't execute my content script.

This is what I try to do:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: /^https?:\/\/play\.spotify\.com\/apps\/player\/.+/,
    attachTo: ["frame"],
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("content.js")]
});
```

Has anyone any idea what could be wrong? How can I make it match?

See:
https://bitbucket.org/panzi/play-control/src/f1dbd217661c0f09d3615dce7b8b1cab9f8fbf70/browser-plugin/firefox/playcontrol-spotify/lib/main.js?at=default

The same thing for Chrome works perfectly well:
https://bitbucket.org/panzi/play-control/src/f1dbd217661c0f09d3615dce7b8b1cab9f8fbf70/browser-plugin/chrome/playcontrol-spotify/?at=default

Answer (score 1):

I'm a regex noob, but in the [doc examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/util_match-pattern#Regular_Expressions), they don't use `^` even when the string starts with 'http'.

Try getting progressively more stringent to see which part of the regex it doesn't like. Throw an `onAttach: console.log("pageMod attached"),` in there to make sure it isn't being attached and something else isn't causing the problem.

`/.*play\.spotify\.com\/apps\/player.*/` If this works, then either it doesn't like the beginning or the end. Try:

- `/https?:\/\/play\.spotify\.com\/apps\/player.*/`
- `/^https?:\/\/play\.spotify\.com\/apps\/player.*/`
- `.*play\.spotify\.com\/apps\/player\/.*/`
- `.*play\.spotify\.com\/apps\/player\/.+/`

If all of the above work, then your string should work too.

Comment: Strange thing: Today it works without changes. (The matching, not the whole add-on.) Don't know what was wrong yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

URL matching works the way I've written it. The bug was something else.